# ' UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment '

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am making a microphone class that recognize user voice. It gives me an `UnboundLocalError`. That happens when I add a `return command` to the `mic_config()` method.

````py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
from speaker import Speaker


class Microphone:
    """Microphone class that represent mic and get user's voice..."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializing of class"""
        self.recognizer = sr.Recognizer()  # Voice recognizer
        self.microphone = sr.Microphone()  # Mic

    def mic_config(self):
        try:
            with self.microphone as source:  # Getting mic
            print('Listening...')
            voice = self.recognizer.listen(source)
            command = self.recognizer.recognize_google(voice, language='en-IN')  # Using google api
            print(command)  

        except: 
            pass
            return command


m1 = Microphone()  # just a test
m1.mic_config()```
````

Comment: I want what user said for command

Comment: But what do you want to do in the event of an error, I can change my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah as Carcigenicate said it is because command is only defined in the try block. This means that if there is an error then command is not defined. I don't know if it is just in the code you posted here but there is an indent error in the with statement

```
try:
    with self.microphone as source:
        print('Listening...')
        voice = self.recognizer.listen(source)
        command = self.recognizer.recognize_google(voice, language='en-IN')
        print(command)

except: 
    raise CustomError
    # or return None, command = None, etc just define command before the last line
    # or don't let the function reach the return command statement

return command
```

Comment: what errors can put in the except clause?

Comment: Any error will stop the program, I just put a custom error if you wanted to define one yourself but for example a simple `raise ValueError` will stop the function from continuing

Comment: Usually you want it to be a bit more descriptive so you know what exactly went wrong but that is up to you